# Powershell Script for Copying a zip file everytime from one location to other with creating a new folder in the destination whenever a TFS build runs

Tags: powershell, tfs, build, visual-studio-2015

Hi Can any one help on this. I have a situation where i need a powershell script to run from TFS build under post build section, it has to copy the zip file generated to some location locally with the build number or build name every time a build happens.

Comment: We can help you if you have a specific question. We will not write the entire script for you. Show what you have tried yourself and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using XAML build or vNext build?

Comment: Hi Im using a XAML build, i'm doing a automated build that publish in azure, i want the zip file generated in the build agent folder need to be copied to some local location in the same build machine say d:/folder/DEV-buildno.zip. How can i get a build name or version or how can i pass in the powershell script.

Comment: Use TFS Build environment variables: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh850448%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you use TFS 2015, it's suggest using the new build system, as there is already a [Copy Files](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files) task in the new build system, you can use it directly.

[image]

Detailed information of this task, you can refer to: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/CopyFiles

Comment: Hi i need a script (bat or ps.1) to generate node_modules as they are not checked in by the team to the repository. The build agent folder "D:builds\2\projectname\buildname\src\code\". I need the node_modules inside that "D:builds\2\projectname\buildname\src\code\ "folder where my package.json and rest of the code is present.  my script with "npm install" command is firing at "D:builds\2\projectname\buildname\src\" with npm err saying package.json is not found and some other NPM errs.